# Task Manager and Resource Monitor Network Monitoring Disagree

Tags: windows, task-manager, resource-monitor

Task Manager is showing some 300,000 B/s (300 KB/s) being received (see screenshot) consistently.

[image: resource monitor fail]

When I opened Resource Monitor to see what executable was doing this... Resource Monitor comes up with nothing in the Network Tab!!!

This is crazy.  What gives?  This is also happening on my other computers in the same network.  One is Windows XP, the other is Windows 10.  The one I took the screenshot on is Windows 7.

UPDATE #1:  I have unplugged everything from the router except one computer and the wireless radio is off.  The computer was still receiving this 'ghost' traffic and Resource Monitor was still showing no processes with Network Activity.  **The router is a PK5001A (CenturyLink)**.

UPDATE #2:  I rebooted the router and it seems to have stopped this ghost network traffic **so far**.  So I could understand some process/application/service getting hung and downloading data over and over, but there was no hanging process.

**It seems that all the computers network cards were either receiving or being given garbage ghost data from the router.** The weird thing is that it was not going or being handled by any process because Resource Monitor did not detect any process using the Network!

**Question 1. How is this even possible?

Question 2. Why is Resource Monitor and Task Manager showing two different things?

Question 3. Why is Resource Monitor not showing which process is receiving the data, or *IS THERE EVEN* any process receiving the data?  If not where is it going?**